# awk Vs. grep Vs ?? and best practices for signalling lines of a file to be extracted

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a folder with multiple files. I would like to create three new `.txt` files from the contents of these files. To achieve this, I thought I would create `begin`/`end` tags to mark the different parts of the file to be used to create the 3 new documents.

For example, the 1st file `01_FileName.mac` would have the structure:

```
/* 01_FileName */

/* START HEADER */
 Header 1 Content
/* END HEADER */

/* START SCRIPT */
    Script 1 Content
/* END SCRIPT */

/* START COMMENTS */
    Comments 1 Content
/* END COMMENTS */
```

and similarly, the 2nd input file `02_FileName.mac`:

```
/* 02_FileName */

/* START HEADER */
 Header 2 Content
/* END HEADER */

/* START SCRIPT */
    Script 2 Content
/* END SCRIPT */

/* START COMMENTS */
    Comments 2 Content
/* END COMMENTS */
```

N.B. there are more than 2 such files.

And I'd like to produce the following three new documents:

1. `Concatenated_Header.txt`:

   ```
   Header 1 Content
   Header 2 Content
   ```
2. `Concatenated_Script.txt`:

   ```
    Script 1 Content
    Script 2 Content
   ```
3. `Concatenated_Load_Commands.txt`:

   ```
   push("<NameOfCurrentPath>")$
      load("<NameOfCurrentPath>/01_FileName.mac")$
      load("<NameOfCurrentPath>/02_FileName.mac")$
   ```

I have seen related examples that involve concatenating a specific line, or lines with a specific string, but not a general approach for demarcating `start`'s and `end`'s for parts to be combined into new, separate files.

N.B. The specific structure of the file is not actually important: any document structure that facilitates the exporting of these parts (`fileName`, `Header Content`, `Script Content` and `Comments Content`) would be great. The goal is just to be able to store all the information related to a script in a single file, while being able to create these three new files. This is just how I imagined `start` and `end` tags might be used to facilitate the process.

(Please see this [earlier revision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/623360/2) for a lot more context and details)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'function prnt(type, pr){ print pr >"concatenated_"type".txt"; };
     FNR==1{ type="load";
             if (!path) {
                 path=FILENAME; sub("[^/]+$","",path);
                 prnt(type, "push(\"<"path">\")$");
              };
              prnt(type,"\tload(\"<"FILENAME">\")$");
           };
     /START HEADER/{ prn=1; type="header"; next; };
     /START SCRIPT/{ prn=1; type="script"; next; };
     /END SCRIPT/ || /END HEADER/{ prn=0; };
prn{ prnt(type, $0); }' /home/User/Unix/*.mac
```

---

We defined an *awk* function; `prnt` is its name and with two parameters, one is used to get a short string and is used as part of output filename to which the lines should written into it where that line it comes from `pr` parameter.

```
function prnt(type, pr){ print pr >"concatenated_"type".txt"; }
```

The parameter `type` value changes conditionally; if it's a first line of input `FNR==1`, we set to `type="load"` to records files' name and path, but *path* should only be written once so we used `if(!path) { path=FILENAME; ...; }` to make sure it will write once (next time `path` variable already take a value, so block within if statement will not run for *path* part again). for the rest of inputs we will only write filename and this also done once per file when `FNR==1`.

if a line was contains `/START HEADER/`, we set `type="header"` and accordingly we set `type="script"` when it matches a line with `/START SCRIPT/`; we also used a control variable flag `prn=1` to control when to call our function to print lines to dedicated filename with `prn{ prnt(type, $0); }`.

`next` command is used to start over and read next input line, so it will not proceed following commands and will not write *header-start-line* lines itself in output.

also we reset `prn=0` flag to avoid printing *header-end-line* line.

Comment: I keep getting the following error: "awk: syntax error at source line 1 in function prnt
 context is
 function prnt(type, pr){ print pr >>>  >"concatenated_"type <<< ".txt"; };" any suggestions?

Comment: `print pr >"concatenated_"type".txt"` is undefined behavior per POSIX. You need to put any compound expression on  the right side of output (or input) redirection in round brackets for it to work in an awk, i.e. `print pr >("concatenated_"type".txt")`. Without that, some awks will work as you want, others will produce syntax errors, and others still can do whatever else they like with it and still be POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    out["HEADER"] = "Concatenated_Header.txt"
    out["SCRIPT"] = "Concatenated_Script.txt"
    out["LOAD"]   = "Concatenated_Load_Commands.txt"
}

FNR == 1 {
    if ( NR == 1 ) {
        dir = FILENAME
        sub("/[^/]+$","",dir)
        printf "push(\"%s\")$\n", dir > out["LOAD"]
    }
    printf "   load(\"%s\")$\n", FILENAME > out["LOAD"]
}

block {
    if ( index($0,"/* END ") == 1 ) {
        block=""
    }
    if ( block in out ) {
        print > out[block]
    }
    next
}

index($0,"/* START ") == 1 { block=$3; next }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk $PWD/*.mac
```

```
$ head Concat*
==> Concatenated_Header.txt <==
 Header 1 Content
 Header 2 Content

==> Concatenated_Load_Commands.txt <==
push("/home/foo/tmp")$
   load("/home/foo/tmp/01_FileName.mac")$
   load("/home/foo/tmp/02_FileName.mac")$

==> Concatenated_Script.txt <==
    Script 1 Content
    Script 2 Content
```

If you want to generate an output file for comments too then just add a line `out["COMMENTS"] = "Concatenated_Comments.txt"` in the `BEGIN` section. Ditto for anything else you create `START`..`END` blocks for. Note that the script only searches for `/* START` outside of blocks and `/* END` inside of them, both only at the start of lines, so those strings can appear within your blocks of text without breaking the script.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Am I supposed to save the first block to a folder somewhere? I tried pasting to terminal and it self-executes (i.e. if I paste it, it doesn't wait for me to hit enter) and returns an error `unrecognized token }`. I tried saving the first block to the folder I'm working within and then using `$ awk -f tst.awk $PWD/*.mac` but it says ` source line number 1 source file tst.awk
 context is
  >>>  <<< `

Comment: I figured out that it did indeed need to be saved as a file, but that the first line had to be removed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: When you say `that the first line had to be removed` - do you mean `cat tst.awk`? That's not part of the script, that's the UNIX command to show you the contents of the file that contains the script.

Comment: Yes, I realized that eventually. As I said: complete newb :) Thank you very much for all your help: this makes such a huge difference & would've taken me at least a week, on my own (if I even managed to figure it out). Cheers, RA